# Flutter check ability to scroll

Tags: dart, flutter

Suppose I have a `ScrollController _scrollController;`
Is there a way to check ability to scroll during build function?

I tried somthing like this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final hasScroll = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
```

But as I understand it does't work because `_scrollController` does't attach during `build()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can't use `ScrollController` until it is attached to the `ListView`. You need to use `WidgetsBindingObserver`'s `SchedulerBinding`'s `addPostFrameCallback` method. Here is the simple example demonstrating that.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((duration) {
      // prints true if scrollable else false
      print("isScrollable = ${_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent != 0}"); 
    });
  }

  Widget build() {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      ...
  }
}
```